# Why do all methods inside template in vue object call automatically when click on button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I made a click event on `button` element and call the `increase` method to update counter. I called the `result()` and `result2()` methods on page load. But when I click on `button`, it called automatically. Why do they call?  What is relation of `increase` and `result` methods with each other. How can I made them to call only once?

Code are here:

```
<div id="app">
   <button v-on:click="increase">Click Me</button>
   <p>{{ counter }}</p>
   <p>{{ result() }}</p>
   <p>{{ result2() }}</p>
</div>

<script>
   new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       data: {
          counter: 0
       },
       methods: {
          increase: function() {
            this.counter++
          },
          result: function() {
            console.log('Hi I m result');   
          },
          result2: function() {
            console.log('Hi I m result 2'); 
          }
       }
   })
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use a method for static values. Use a variable instead

Comment: It also try it with v-on:click="counter++". But it still call every function.

Comment: I was referring to `result` and `result2`, your increase function is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update the `counter` property the DOM will be re rendered and call every property in your script like  data, computed properties and methods, if you want to only call that methods in the page load you could use call them inside the `mounted` hook :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    counter: 0
  }),
  methods: {
    increase: function() {
      this.counter++
    },
    result: function() {
      console.log('Hi I m result');
    },
    result2: function() {
      console.log('Hi I m result 2');
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.result();
    this.result2()
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="increase" class="btn">Click Me</button>
  <p>{{ counter }}</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no relation. Whenever your component is re-rendered all your mustaches {{ }} will be evaluated if they call methods.